# NotFoundError: No registered 'ZerosLike' OpKernel for GPU/ tf.eager and keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, kernel, gpu, eager

I had written down my own network reproducing [pix2pixHD](https://github.com/NVIDIA/pix2pixHD). This is a simple modification of [pix2pix](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/pix2pix/pix2pix_eager.ipynb#scrollTo=lFPI4Nu-8b4q) just replicating Generators into two, and discriminators into three, which are handling different level of resolutions.

But when I try to train, it keeps returning `Opkernel_zeroslike unfound error` but can't find why this error occurred.

I had generally modified [pix2pix](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/pix2pix/pix2pix_eager.ipynb#scrollTo=lFPI4Nu-8b4q) to make this code and [pix2pix](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/pix2pix/pix2pix_eager.ipynb#scrollTo=lFPI4Nu-8b4q) doesn't reutrn error and well succeded to train.

Any hint about this `Opkernel unfound error`?

```
#### this sciprt based on tensorflow v.1.10

#!pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==1.10.0 #normally the default provided by aws is 1.8.0

# Keras Implementation of pix2pix 

import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"

import sys
import time
import glob
import random
from functools import reduce

import cv2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import clear_output


import scipy
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

from tensorflow.python.data import Dataset
from tensorflow.python.data import Iterator
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops

import collections
import math
import time

import util

now = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

# Paths

data = './data/ipx_2'
PATH = os.path.join(data, 'train')
image_paths = sorted(glob.glob(PATH+"/*"))

# Hypers

BUFFER_SIZE = len(image_paths) 
IMG_WIDTH = 256
IMG_HEIGHT = 256
BATCH_SIZE = {IMG_WIDTH == 256 : 16, IMG_WIDTH == 512: 10}.get(True, "IMG_WIDTH must be either 256 or 512")
TIME_SPACE = 11
print(BUFFER_SIZE, BATCH_SIZE, IMG_HEIGHT, TIME_SPACE) #for sanity check 

# I/O Utils

def load_image(image_path, diff = True, corr =True, time_space = TIME_SPACE):

    image = tf.read_file(image_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_png(image)

    w = tf.shape(image)[0]
    print(w)    

    target_image = image[:, -w:, :]
    input_image = image[:, :-w, :]

    input_image = tf.reshape(input_image, [256,256,66])
    target_image = tf.reshape(target_image, [256,256,3])

    target_image = tf.cast(target_image, tf.float32)
    input_image = tf.cast(input_image, tf.float32)

    # normalizing the images to [-1, 1]
    target_image = (target_image / 127.5) - 1
    input_image = (input_image / 127.5) - 1

    return input_image, target_image

EPOCHS = int(1e+3)

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH+'/*.png')
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda x: load_image(x))
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
print(train_dataset)

# Generator

OUTPUT_CHANNELS = 3

class Downsample(tf.keras.Model): #conv2d && Lrelu
    def __init__(self, filters, size=4, apply_batchnorm=True, first = False):
        super(Downsample, self).__init__()
        self.apply_batchnorm = apply_batchnorm
        self.first = first 
        initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.02)

        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, 
                                            (size, size), 
                                            strides=2, 
                                            padding='same',
                                            kernel_initializer=initializer,
                                            use_bias=False)
        if self.apply_batchnorm:
            self.batchnorm = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()

    def call(self, x, training):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        if self.apply_batchnorm:
            x = self.batchnorm(x, training=training)
        if not self.first:
            x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x)
        return x 

class Upsample(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, filters, size, apply_dropout=False, first = False):
        super(Upsample, self).__init__()
        self.apply_dropout = apply_dropout
        self.first = first 
        initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.02)

        self.up_conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters, 
                                                       (size, size), 
                                                       strides=2, 
                                                       padding='same',
                                                       kernel_initializer=initializer,
                                                       use_bias=False)

        self.refine = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, 
                                            (3, 3), 
                                            strides=1, 
                                            padding='same',
                                            kernel_initializer=initializer,
                                            use_bias=False)

        self.batchnorm = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()

        if self.apply_dropout:
            self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5) #drop_out rate here 

    def call(self, x1, x2, training):
        x = self.up_conv(x1)
        x = self.batchnorm(x, training=training)
        if self.apply_dropout:
            x = self.dropout(x, training=training)
        x = self.refine(x)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        x = self.refine(x)        
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        if not self.first:
            x = tf.concat([x, x2], axis=-1)

        return x

class Generator(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.02)

        self.down1 = Downsample(64, 4, first = True)
        self.down2 = Downsample(128, 4)
        self.down3 = Downsample(256, 4)
        self.down4 = Downsample(512, 4)
        self.down5 = Downsample(512, 4)
        self.down6 = Downsample(512, 4)
        self.down7 = Downsample(512, 4)
        self.down8 = Downsample(512, 4)

        self.up1 = Upsample(512, 4, apply_dropout=True, first = True)
        self.up2 = Upsample(512, 4, apply_dropout=True)
        self.up3 = Upsample(512, 4, apply_dropout=True)
        self.up4 = Upsample(512, 4)
        self.up5 = Upsample(256, 4)
        self.up6 = Upsample(128, 4)
        self.up7 = Upsample(64, 4)

        self.last = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(OUTPUT_CHANNELS, 
                                                    (4, 4), 
                                                    strides=2, 
                                                    padding='same',
                                                    kernel_initializer=initializer)

    @tf.contrib.eager.defun
    def call(self, x, training):
        # x shape == (bs, 256, 256, 3)    
        x1 = self.down1(x, training=training) # (bs, 128, 128, 64)
        x2 = self.down2(x1, training=training) # (bs, 64, 64, 128)
        x3 = self.down3(x2, training=training) # (bs, 32, 32, 256)
        x4 = self.down4(x3, training=training) # (bs, 16, 16, 512)
        x5 = self.down5(x4, training=training) # (bs, 8, 8, 512)
        x6 = self.down6(x5, training=training) # (bs, 4, 4, 512)
        x7 = self.down7(x6, training=training) # (bs, 2, 2, 512)
        x8 = self.down8(x7, training=training) # (bs, 1, 1, 512)

        x9 = self.up1(x8, x7, training=training) # (bs, 2, 2, 1024)
        x10 = self.up2(x9, x6, training=training) # (bs, 4, 4, 1024)
        x11 = self.up3(x10, x5, training=training) # (bs, 8, 8, 1024)
        x12 = self.up4(x11, x4, training=training) # (bs, 16, 16, 1024)
        x13 = self.up5(x12, x3, training=training) # (bs, 32, 32, 512)
        x14 = self.up6(x13, x2, training=training) # (bs, 64, 64, 256)
        x15 = self.up7(x14, x1, training=training) # (bs, 128, 128, 128)

        x16 = self.last(x15) # (bs, 256, 256, 3)
        x16 = tf.nn.tanh(x16)

        return x16

# Discriminator

class DiscDownsample(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, filters, size, apply_batchnorm=True, first = False):
        super(DiscDownsample, self).__init__()
        self.first = first 
        self.apply_batchnorm = apply_batchnorm
        initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.02)

        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, 
                                            (size, size), 
                                            strides=2, 
                                            padding='same',
                                            kernel_initializer=initializer,
                                            use_bias=False)
        if self.apply_batchnorm:
            self.batchnorm = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()

    def call(self, x, training):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        if self.apply_batchnorm:
            x = self.batchnorm(x, training=training)
        x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x)
        return x 

class Discriminator(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
        initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.02)

        self.down1 = DiscDownsample(64, 4, False)
        self.down2 = DiscDownsample(128, 4)
        self.down3 = DiscDownsample(256, 4)

        # we are zero padding here with 1 because we need our shape to 
        # go from (batch_size, 32, 32, 256) to (batch_size, 31, 31, 512)
        self.zero_pad1 = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D()
        self.conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, 
                                           (4, 4), 
                                           strides=1, 
                                           kernel_initializer=initializer, 
                                           use_bias=False)
        self.batchnorm1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()

        # shape change from (batch_size, 31, 31, 512) to (batch_size, 30, 30, 1)
        self.zero_pad2 = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D()
        self.last = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, 
                                           (4, 4), 
                                           strides=1,
                                           kernel_initializer=initializer)

    @tf.contrib.eager.defun
    def call(self, inp, tar, training):
        # concatenating the input and the target
        x = tf.concat([inp, tar], axis=-1) # (bs, 256, 256, channels*2)
        x = self.down1(x, training=training) # (bs, 128, 128, 64)
        x = self.down2(x, training=training) # (bs, 64, 64, 128)
        x = self.down3(x, training=training) # (bs, 32, 32, 256)

        x = self.zero_pad1(x) # (bs, 34, 34, 256)
        x = self.conv(x)      # (bs, 31, 31, 512)
        x = self.batchnorm1(x, training=training)
        x = tf.nn.leaky_relu(x)

        x = self.zero_pad2(x) # (bs, 33, 33, 512)
        # don't add a sigmoid activation here since
        # the loss function expects raw logits.
        x = self.last(x)      # (bs, 30, 30, 1)

        return x

generator = Generator()
discriminator = Discriminator()

# Loss and Opter

LAMBDA = 100 #param for l1_loss

def discriminator_loss(disc_real_output, disc_generated_output):
    real_loss = tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(multi_class_labels = tf.ones_like(disc_real_output), 
                                              logits = disc_real_output)
    generated_loss = tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(multi_class_labels = tf.zeros_like(disc_generated_output), 
                                                   logits = disc_generated_output)

    total_disc_loss = real_loss + generated_loss

    return total_disc_loss

def generator_loss(disc_generated_output, gen_output, target):
    gan_loss = tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(multi_class_labels = tf.ones_like(disc_generated_output),
                                             logits = disc_generated_output) 
    # mean absolute error
    l1_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(target - gen_output))

    total_gen_loss = gan_loss + (LAMBDA * l1_loss) 

    return total_gen_loss

generator_optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(2e-4, beta1=0.5)
discriminator_optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(2e-4, beta1=0.5)

# ckpt

checkpoint_dir = os.path.join('./log/', now)
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt")
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(generator_optimizer=generator_optimizer,
                                 discriminator_optimizer=discriminator_optimizer,
                                 generator=generator,
                                 discriminator=discriminator)

# Train

def generate_images(epoch, step, model, test_input, tar, logDir):
    # the training=True is intentional here since
    # we want the batch statistics while running the model
    # on the test dataset. If we use training=False, we will get 
    # the accumulated statistics learned from the training dataset
    # (which we don't want)
    prediction = model(test_input, training=True)

    ## for disply the plots, it takes 1.2sec 
    display_list = [tar[0], prediction[0]]

    img1 = (tar[0] + 1.) * 127.5
    img2 = (prediction[0] + 1.) * 127.5
    img3 = np.append(img1, img2, axis = 1)
    img3 = cv2.cvtColor(img3, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    image_name = "step-" + str(epoch+1) + "-"+ str(step) + ".jpg"
    mkdirs(logDir + "/images/")
    cv2.imwrite(logDir + "/images/" + image_name, img3)

def train(dataset, epochs):  
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        if (epoch + 1) % 6 == 0:
            epoch_start = time.time()

        mkdirs(checkpoint_dir)

        for step , (input_image, target) in enumerate(dataset):
            if step % 100 == 0:
                step_start = time.time()
            with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
                gen_output = generator(input_image, training=True)

                disc_real_output = discriminator(input_image, target, training=True)
                disc_generated_output = discriminator(input_image, gen_output, training=True)

                gen_loss = generator_loss(disc_generated_output, gen_output, target)
                disc_loss = discriminator_loss(disc_real_output, disc_generated_output)

            generator_gradients = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss, 
                                                  generator.variables)
            discriminator_gradients = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss, 
                                                       discriminator.variables)

            generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(generator_gradients, 
                                                  generator.variables))
            discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(discriminator_gradients, 
                                                      discriminator.variables))

            if step % 100 == 0:
                print('Time taken for step {} of epoch {} is {} sec\n'.format(step + 1, epoch+1,
                                            time.time()-step_start))
                clear_output(wait=True)
                for inp, tar in dataset.take(1):
                    generate_images(epoch, step, generator, inp, tar, checkpoint_dir)

        # saving (checkpoint) the model every 6 epochs
        if (epoch + 1) % 6 == 0:
            print('Time taken for epoch {} is {} sec\n'.format(epoch + 1,
                                                        time.time()-epoch_start))
            checkpoint.save(file_prefix = checkpoint_prefix)

train(train_dataset, EPOCHS)
```

error

```
NotFoundError: No registered 'ZerosLike' OpKernel for GPU devices compatible with node Func/_191 = ZerosLike[T=DT_RESOURCE](downsample_conv2d_conv2d_readvariableop_resource)
     (OpKernel was found, but attributes didn't match)
    .  Registered:  device='CPU'; T in [DT_VARIANT]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_STRING]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_BOOL]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX128]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_BFLOAT16]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT8]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_UINT8]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT16]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_UINT16]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT64]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_INT32]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_VARIANT]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_INT64]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX128]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX64]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_BFLOAT16]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_BOOL]

     [[Node: Func/_191 = ZerosLike[T=DT_RESOURCE](downsample_conv2d_conv2d_readvariableop_resource)]]
     [[Node: gradients/generator_1/StatefulPartitionedCall_grad/SymbolicGradient = SymbolicGradient[Tin=[DT_FLOAT, DT_RESOURCE, DT_RESOURCE, DT_RESOURCE, DT_RESOURCE, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], Tout=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], f=__forward___inference_call_1463_1839[Tin=[DT_FLOAT, DT_RESOURCE, DT_RESOURCE, DT_RESOURCE, DT_RESOURCE, ..., DT_RESOURCE, DT_RESOURCE, DT_RESOURCE, DT_RESOURCE, DT_RESOURCE], Tout=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], f=__forward___inference_call_1463_1839[]], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](resize_images_resizebilinear, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_1, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_2, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_3, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_4, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_5, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_6, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_7, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_8, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_9, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_10, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_11, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_12, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_13, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_14, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_15, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_16, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_17, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_18, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_19, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_20, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_21, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_22, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_23, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_24, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_25, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_26, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_27, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_28, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_29, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_30, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_31, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_32, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_33, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_34, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_35, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_36, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_37, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_38, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_39, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_40, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_41, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_42, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_43, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_44, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_45, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_46, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_47, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_48, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_49, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_50, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_51, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_52, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_53, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_54, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_55, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_56, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_57, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_58, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_59, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_60, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_61, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_62, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_63, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_64, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_65, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_66, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_67, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_68, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_69, generator_1_statefulpartitionedcall_args_70, gradients/downsample_6/conv2d_24/Conv2D_grad/Conv2DBackpropInput, gradients/zeros_like_88, gradients/zeros_like_89, gradients/zeros_like_90, gradients/zeros_like_91, gradients/zeros_like_92, gradients/zeros_like_93, gradients/zeros_like_94, gradients/zeros_like_95, gradients/zeros_like_96, gradients/zeros_like_97, gradients/zeros_like_98, gradients/zeros_like_99, gradients/zeros_like_100, gradients/zeros_like_101, gradients/zeros_like_102, gradients/zeros_like_103, gradients/zeros_like_104, gradients/zeros_like_105, gradients/zeros_like_106, gradients/zeros_like_107, gradients/zeros_like_108, gradients/zeros_like_109, gradients/zeros_like_110, gradients/zeros_like_111, gradients/zeros_like_112, gradients/zeros_like_113, gradients/zeros_like_114, gradients/zeros_like_115, gradients/zeros_like_116, gradients/zeros_like_117, gradients/zeros_like_118, gradients/zeros_like_119, gradients/zeros_like_120, gradients/zeros_like_121, gradients/zeros_like_122, gradients/zeros_like_123, gradients/zeros_like_124, gradients/zeros_like_125, gradients/zeros_like_126, gradients/zeros_like_127, gradients/zeros_like_128, gradients/zeros_like_129, gradients/zeros_like_130, gradients/zeros_like_131, gradients/zeros_like_132, gradients/zeros_like_133, gradients/zeros_like_134, gradients/zeros_like_135, gradients/zeros_like_136, gradients/zeros_like_137, gradients/zeros_like_138, gradients/zeros_like_139, gradients/zeros_like_140, gradients/zeros_like_141, gradients/zeros_like_142, gradients/zeros_like_143, gradients/zeros_like_144, gradients/zeros_like_145, gradients/zeros_like_146, gradients/zeros_like_147, gradients/zeros_like_148, gradients/zeros_like_149, gradients/zeros_like_150, gradients/zeros_like_151, gradients/zeros_like_152, gradients/zeros_like_153, gradients/zeros_like_154, gradients/zeros_like_155, gradients/zeros_like_156, gradients/zeros_like_157, gradients/zeros_like_158, gradients/zeros_like_159, gradients/zeros_like_160, gradients/zeros_like_161, gradients/zeros_like_162, gradients/zeros_like_163, gradients/zeros_like_164, gradients/zeros_like_165, gradients/zeros_like_166, gradients/zeros_like_167, gradients/zeros_like_168, gradients/zeros_like_169, gradients/zeros_like_170, gradients/zeros_like_171, gradients/zeros_like_172, gradients/zeros_like_173, gradients/zeros_like_174, gradients/zeros_like_175, gradients/zeros_like_176, gradients/zeros_like_177, gradients/zeros_like_178, gradients/zeros_like_179, gradients/zeros_like_180, gradients/zeros_like_181, gradients/zeros_like_182, gradients/zeros_like_183, gradients/zeros_like_184, gradients/zeros_like_185, gradients/zeros_like_186, gradients/zeros_like_187, gradients/zeros_like_188, gradients/zeros_like_189, gradients/zeros_like_190, gradients/zeros_like_191, gradients/zeros_like_192, gradients/zeros_like_193, gradients/zeros_like_194, gradients/zeros_like_195, gradients/zeros_like_196, gradients/zeros_like_197, gradients/zeros_like_198, gradients/zeros_like_199, gradients/zeros_like_200, gradients/zeros_like_201, gradients/zeros_like_202, gradients/zeros_like_203, gradients/zeros_like_204, gradients/zeros_like_205, gradients/zeros_like_206, gradients/zeros_like_207, gradients/zeros_like_208, gradients/zeros_like_209, gradients/zeros_like_210, gradients/zeros_like_211, gradients/zeros_like_212, gradients/zeros_like_213, gradients/zeros_like_214, gradients/zeros_like_215, gradients/zeros_like_216, gradients/zeros_like_217, gradients/zeros_like_218, gradients/zeros_like_219, gradients/zeros_like_220, gradients/zeros_like_221, gradients/zeros_like_222, gradients/zeros_like_223, gradients/zeros_like_224, gradients/zeros_like_225, gradients/zeros_like_226, gradients/zeros_like_227, gradients/zeros_like_228, gradients/zeros_like_229, gradients/zeros_like_230, gradients/zeros_like_231, gradients/zeros_like_232, gradients/zeros_like_233, gradients/zeros_like_234, gradients/zeros_like_235, gradients/zeros_like_236, gradients/zeros_like_237, gradients/zeros_like_238, gradients/zeros_like_239, gradients/zeros_like_240, gradients/zeros_like_241, gradients/zeros_like_242, gradients/zeros_like_243, gradients/zeros_like_244, gradients/zeros_like_245, gradients/zeros_like_246, gradients/zeros_like_247, gradients/zeros_like_248, gradients/zeros_like_249, gradients/zeros_like_250, gradients/zeros_like_251, gradients/zeros_like_252, gradients/zeros_like_253, gradients/zeros_like_254, gradients/zeros_like_255, gradients/zeros_like_256, gradients/zeros_like_257, gradients/zeros_like_258, gradients/zeros_like_259, gradients/zeros_like_260, gradients/zeros_like_261)]] [Op:PartitionedCall]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the same issue, it seems that there is no definite answer to this issue for the moment. You can check the evolution on Tensorflow's github dedicated issue : 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20369

However, it was pointed out that the reason may be related to the fact some data types (such as `int32`) are not handled by the GPU but by the CPU in tensorflow. Therefore, your issue could be fixed by changing the type of the problematic variable to `uint32` or `int64`.